# Ending with the first in two different ways

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Presenting a different face
To the outside rather than the inside place
Who was it?
It was me, not just me, but a little bit
Speaking 'yes' as the conquistadors did during their days
Ending with the first in two different ways

What am I?

Hint:

> The answer is a word made up of letters that are the answers for different sections of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

If

> each line is a clue to a letter

then you could be an onomatopoetic

> **CRUNCH**.
> "C" I'm not sure about.
> "R" has a tail pointing out from what would otherwise be a "P".
> "U" (="you") is the answer to "Who was it?".
> "N" is pronounced ["en", which is, visually, a partial "em"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash_versus_em_dash), which is not quite "me".
> "C" is pronounced "sí", which is Spanish for "yes".
> "H" can be formed by taking the first letter on this list - "C" - and putting two of them back to back, then rotating 90 degrees.

Comment: Sorry, no. Good try